# built and execute a maven-project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-plugin

I am trying to **build** and **run** a project using maven and under eclipse Kepler.  I know that I shoud run (under linux using Terminal) the following commands to build and execute my project:

```
mvn clean install

mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.App"
```

But I want to know, how to build and execute my project under eclipse.

In my eclipse, I have six commands at all: maven build, maven build..., maven clean, maven generate-sources,  maven install and maven test.

How to **built** and **execute** my project on **Eclipse**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, the solution is as following:

```
right-click on  pom.com  -> you get many options-> you choose built->
enter in launch configuration: clean compile package -> click ok
```

After the build-process is finished, click on your application.java and click run (green button). That´s all